# Make two words stick together on responsive design

Tags: html, css

I have two words that needs to stick together all the time because it's the name of the company. The company's name is, for example, S Overflow. Sometimes, The second word 'Overflow' goes down on second paragraph on certain screen widths.

***Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet met S 

Overflow consectidur***

Is there a way  that no matter the screen size is, those two words will come stick together as one all the time?

***Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet met S Overflow 
 consectidur***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it’s a matter of two words separated by a space, with no special characters (like hyphens) involved, the simplest and most robust way is to use a no-break space, e.g.

```
S&nbsp;Overflow
```

You can alternatively wrap the name in an element and set `white-space: nowrap` on it. This is convenient if the name is wrapped in an element anyway, e.g. for styling.

Comment: I didn't know about this before. Thanks! I think I'll be using &nbsp for now but that white-space is also working.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is white-space: nowrap in css:

Css:

```
.doNotWrap {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Html:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit ammet met <span class="doNotWrap">S Overflow</span>
consectidur
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to create some css rules to control the company name that is contained within a span tag with a fixed width and display set to block.

```
<span class="cName">company name</span>
```

check a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/05L2qjrL/)

Another approach would be to use media queries to ensure the company name appears on one line across different device sizes.